# Buttons not working on Mobile Product page

Tags: css, button, mobile

For some reason, when visiting my website on my android phone, I couldn't click most of the buttons on this page: http://ininkk.com/product/cant-recycle-wasted-time/

Does anybody know why that is? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT --

On mobile, these elements inside `#content-left` are set to float left and float right respectively:

1. `<div class="images">`
2. `<div class="summary entry-summary">`

---

1. Your form with id `searchform` covers the entire lower half of the page.
2. An `<li>` with the class of `empty` inside the div `widget_shopping_cart_content` also covers the entire lower half of the page.

Examine and adjust the css for these elements and the buttons will work.

To determine this, I right-clicked on the elements I couldn't click in Google Chrome, selected `inspect element` and it shows in the developer tools which element you're selecting.

Comment: It seems to be your `.content-left` and `.content-right` containers, although I'm still not seeing exactly what is affecting their position to create this side effect.

Comment: Do you mean  "#woocommerce_widget_cart-4 > div > ul > li"?

Comment: Because these two elements are floated, the parent with `position: relative;`, in this case `#content-left` has 0 height. This causes the element below (`#content-right`) to flow upwards, covering the previous content.

Comment: Going to test this out; will let you know how it goes!

Comment: It worked! Essentially I used the following code to take away the searchform and .empty attributes away:

    .empty{
    display:none;
}

    #searchform{
    display: none;
}